# Blank space appear in the imageview after set the scaletype

Tags: android

I am new to the android and set the image in the imageview. Image is large in the size so i set the scaleType="FIT_START" but it make some blank space at the bottom of image.. Please help me why its blank space after this. If I set the scaleType="FitXY" then it take complete space.

I want after the scaleType="FIT_START" then there should not blank space.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so you don't want it to take complete space?

Comment: Yes,,I want to maintain the aspect ratio and it should not show the blank space. I used this `scaleType="FIT_START" ` but it appear blank space also

Comment: Try `scaleType="CENTER_CROP"`

Comment: use scaleType="FIT_XY"

Comment: @Manishika I can't use the FitXY because it does not maintain the aspect ratio of the image

Comment: @PareshMayani scaleType="CENTER_CROP" but it leave the top and bottom few blank space

Comment: @Williams post your XML, without it no one can suggest you exactly!

Comment: use scaleType = CENTER_INSIDE to maintain the aspect ratio.. and make width and height of imageView to WRAP_CONTENT

Answer (score 0):

According to [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.ScaleToFit.html#FILL)

**FIT_START**

> Compute a scale that will maintain the original src aspect ratio, but
>   will also ensure that src fits entirely inside dst. At least one axis
>   (X or Y) will fit exactly. START aligns the result to the left and top
>   edges of dst.

**FIT_XY**

> Scale in X and Y independently, so that src matches dst exactly. This
>   may change the aspect ratio of the src.

Comment: I can't use the FitXY because it does not maintain the aspect ratio of the image

Comment: Blank space is appearing because your container is bigger than the image. Although you should never Stretch or shrink the image as long as you need it, You should set the attributes of container of image as WRAP_CONTENT or you should use a bigger image that has the same dimensions as of your container.